# How do I turn on the new Google Spreadsheets for Service Accounts

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use the new Google Spreadsheets with a API service account.  It is easy to turn on for a personal account but how do I turn it on for a service account?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring Google Sheets

Comment: It is on topic because Service Accounts are used for making Google Drive API requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic method to create new sheets and service accounts cannot be logged into interactively. Thus new sheets cannot be created by a service account. You can share a new sheet with a service account however this is somewhat pointless as you can't access new sheets via the Spreadsheet api.